# Lucene.net GetFieldQuery vs TermQuery

Tags: lucene

Using Lucene's standard analyzer. Title field in question is non-stored, analyzed. The query is as follows:

```
title:"Some-Url-Friendly-Title"
```

In Luke, this query gets correctly re-written as:

```
title:"some url friendly title" (- replaced by whitespace, everything lowercased).
```

I *thought* the Lucene.net version would be:

```
new TermQuery(new Term("title","Some-Url-Friendly-Title"))
```

However, no results are returned.

Then I tried:

```
_parser.GetFieldQuery("title","Some-Url-Friendly-Title")
```

And it worked as expected!

Both queries were executed via:
    _searcher.Search([query object], [sort object])

Can somebody point me in the right direction to see what the differences between TermQuery and _parser.GetFieldQuery() are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`TermQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html) is much simpler than running a query through a queryparser.  Not only is it not lowercased, and doesn't understand to break up hyphenated terms, it isn't even tokenized.  It just searches for the term you tell it to look for.  That means it is looking for the term "Some-Url-Friendly-Title" as a single untokenized keyword, in your index.  I assume you are using an analyzer, so chances are no such tokens exist.

To take it a step further, if you had been searching for "Some Url Friendly Title" as the  Term text, you still wouldn't come up with anything, since it's looking for "Some Url Friendly Title" as a Single Token, not as the four tokens (or rather, terms) in your index.

If you look at what a the [standard query parser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html) generates when you parse your query, you'll see that TermQueries are only one of the building blocks it uses to generate the complete query, along with [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html), and possibly [PhraseQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html), [PrefixQueriy](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html), etc.

Comment: So, by generating a TermQuery and executing it via the searcher does NOT analyze, tokenize the term value that I requested?

I was under the impression that all queries executed via the searher will be appropriately analyzed before being executed. Is this not the case?

Comment: That is not the case.  Generally, the analyzer is applied when indexing (adding or updating) documents, and when parsing queries.  Unless you have added some layer applying an analyzer to queries before they hit the index, of course.  But IndexSearcher, to my knowledge, doesn't really know anything about analyzers (whereas IndexWriter and QueryParser do).

Comment: Thank you. I looked into this further and here is a quote from Manning's Lucene book:
"A single word in a query expression corresponds to a term. A TermQuery is returned from QueryParser if
the expression consists of a single word"
Meaning, my understanding was backwards. I thought creating query objects was a clean way of creating queries and sending them to the searcher. The reality is opposite, you give QueryParser some string, and it then creates a Query object that you then execute on the searcher. Your answer put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

In Lucene.Net version 3.0.3 the GetFieldQuery is inaccessible due to it's protection modifier. Use

```
MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(searchText, field)
```

instead.